# Reviewing mismatch amounts from 2 tables

Tags: plsql

I am trying to write a query that only shows mismatches of amounts from 2 different tables in PL/SQL.  Essentially I am trying to determine if one fee being charged is the old fee or if they are being charged something different.  I only want to display mismatches between the 2 records.  If I get 0 results it means the correct fee was being charged for this month.

No errors just trying to get help with the structure of the query

Comment: Welcome! Please share your table structure, and how those tables are related. Maybe show the query as you have it so far. A snippet of sample data, and expected outcome would be helpful too. To find a mismatch between two records, you first must know _which_ two records. For us readers, it's pretty much impossible to guess what the query should be without having that background info.